# Why can't my test client connect to my WCF rest service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a simple wcf rest service.  I can test it ok using the WCF Test Client.

I created a test client of my own via svcutil.exe. This builds and runs. However, it always gives this exception when instantiating the service object:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'IBookService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This
>   might be because no configuration file was found for your application,
>   or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found
>   in the client element.

I'm basically following the tutorial here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services

I also cannot access the endpoints via a url when running it locally.  It's unclear to me why this tutorial has a .svc file in the url when trying to access the service from a browser though.  I have no .svc files anywhere.

Comment: You'll want to show your app.config/web.config relevant sections.

Comment: With WCF in webapi you are able [self host without a .svc file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx).  All the information to do so is contained in the config file and most of the stuff happens without having to do anything.

Comment: If you're using a REST service, you don't need svcutil. Proxies are used for SOAP services - you'll need to use an HTTP API for consuming a REST service.

Comment: If you've followed the article you linked to, the WCFTestClient was testing the SOAP version of the service, *not* the REST version.  To test REST services, you can use a browser - as the article shows.

Answer (score 1):

The WCF Test Client is for testing **SOAP**-based services (those services using any binding other than `webHttpBinding` in WCF).

The WCF Test Client however is **NOT** capable of working with **REST** services.

For **REST**, use something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) instead.